# large horizontal table - springer journal

Tags: tables

I need to make a table using springer template, but it didn't work with me!

```
\begin{table}
\caption{Please write your table caption here}
\label{tab:1}   
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
Video name &    D1 &    D2 & D3 &   D4 &    D5 &    D6 &    D7 &    D8 &    D9 &    D10  & D11  & D12 & D13\\
\noalign{\smallskip}\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
percentage &    60 &    62 &    64 & 64 &   60 &    90  & 55 &  55 &    55 &    60 &    55 &    60 &    50 \\   
\noalign{\smallskip}\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

unfortunately, I have the following after compile:

[image]

I ned the same style for te table

Comment: The same style as what?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: What "doesn't work"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must have had multiple error messages (so should show the error messages not the output pdf) You have only specified three columns `lll` but have added 14

change `lll` to `*{14}{l}`